# accept visa and masterCard payment in java application

Tags: java, payment, credit-card

I am new to this topic, so I don't know what I need to accept payments using credit cards like visa and master card in my java application.
Please also give me the code I should write in java to fulfill this task.

Comment: You're looking for Stripe.

Comment: That's a tall order, and WAY full of security risk.  Many companies, even larger ones, farm that sort of thing out to companies that are specifically suited to handle it.

Comment: i am open to all solutions, but if you suggest one please tell me how to implement it.

Comment: Sort of, like [__PayPal__](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sdks/) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is a payment processor API like Stripe. See Stripe's API documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs

"Give me the code I should write in Java" is a much, *much* bigger request than you seem to realize. That's like asking an architect to give you detailed instructions for designing and building a house when you don't even know how many rooms it should have. That said, Stripe's documentation provides examples for pretty much every operation - if you have any understanding of Java to start with, you should have no problem consuming the Stripe API.

As a side note, if you wind up storing any credit card information on your server, you are required to adhere to PCI standards: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/hardware_software/

As a second side note, any failure on your part in adherence to PCI or security of your application **makes you responsible for any data theft** and/or resulting fraud. Even if you adhere to PCI, other security issues in your application can allow attackers to steal your customers' sensitive credit card data. Consider carefully when deciding how to accept credit card payments. Using an embedded integration like [Stripe's embedded Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/checkout) insulates you from these responsibilities because Stripe handles all of the actual credit card data.

Comment: thank you,I think that stripes is the same like authorize.net which I found using google.
yes I can read the java code in tutorial,
but I have just 2 questions: 
1- is authorize.net and stripes are the same?
2- are they both free to use?

Comment: Authorize.net and Stripe are not the same company, but they perform the same task - both have payment APIs you can use to programmatically  charge credit cards. Neither are free. Both charge 2.9% + $0.30 per successful transaction. However, Authorize.net also charges a $49 "setup" fee.
https://stripe.com/us/pricing
https://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Payment Processor that can accept payments via credit/debit cards, and that also provides an API that your code can interface with.

Do some searching for 'credit card processor', 'payment processor' and 'java api' or 'web application' or similar and see what you find.

Answer (score 0):

I googled and I found that http://www.authorize.net/  provide good API and examples also.
http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/java/